# Checking for a pattern in a string in JAVA "1.1.7B-2"

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

i want to check if a pattern exists in a given string. how do i do this in java 1.1.7B-2 . i know that java 2 has pattern matching functions. Are there any available in the version 1.1.7B-2?

Comment: as Pattern, Matcher or even String.replaceAll were added in java 1.4 I would say, no...

Comment: Java 1.1?  For real?  Damn, that takes me back...

Comment: What exactly is running a Java 1.1.7 (any build) version, a washing machine?

Comment: tell me about it :-/ .. even parsedecimal does not exist.. i had to split the  string at the decimal point and enter some logic :D

Comment: ok guys.. i think i have a workaround.. can some1 tell me what value readLine() returns at the end of a file. i doubt it is "" coz then if i enter a blank line in the midst of a file it will consider it as the end of file

Comment: @AtishDeepank I think it returns `null` at the end of a line. Most current way to read line by line is `while((d=in.readLine()) != null)`

Answer (score 2):

The ancient [Jakarta ORO](https://jakarta.apache.org/oro/) project contains classes that support pattern matching. You should be able to find a version that works with Java 1.1.

**[EDIT]** If you just want to find a substring, use `String.indexOf(String) >= 0`

Comment: Alternatively, Jakarta Regexp (also dead) - http://jakarta.apache.org/regexp/index.html

Comment: @Aaron Digulla i cant download packages. Basically i want to check if a line contains the string "UA-INS" .. any workarounds will also do